# MongoDB 2.4.x storing GeoJSON objects with short names?

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Previously I was storing two type of geospatial data in my database: points and polygons without holes.

So I had something like this

```js
{
    "a" : 12.0,
    "b" : 12.0,
    "c" : [[12.0, 32.0], [12.0, 32.0], [12.0, 32.0], [12.0, 32.0], [12.0, 32.0]]
}
```

Where (a,b) a = latitude, b = longitude represents a point, and c - is polygon which consists of lat,lng points. I deliberately have this small names to save space (I have pretty big amount of documents in my collection).

Right now I am thinking of switching to GeoJSON, and looking at http://geojson.org/ all I need to do is to change the point with

```js
{
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0]
}
```

and polygon with

```js
{ 
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
    ]
}
```

I understand that I can shorten the names `type` to `t`, `coordinates` to `c`, but is it possible to shorten `Point` and `Polygon` to something like 1 and 2.

If so what queries should look like?
In particular I am interested in the following queries:

1. Find all points inside a specific polygon
2. Find all points near a specific point
3. Find all polygons that intersect with a specific polygon

Comment: Why not store it efficiently (`1` and `2`) and transform it outside of the database to whatever you need?

Comment: Could you explain why not, or why you wouldn't be able to tranform it first?